# Xcode move Storyboard elements more precisely

Tags: xcode, storyboard

Is it possibly to move storyboard elements in smaller steps than it is possibly by pressing the arrow keys on the keyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The arrow key moves the item by a single point. There isn't the option to position elements on sub-point boundaries.